# Is there a way to set up a custom trackpad gesture for Mission Control?

Tags: osx-lion

I was wondering whether it was possible to set-up a custom trackpad gesture for Mission Control. I don't want to swipe up for Mission Control, I'd like to, just like I did with Exposé in SL swipe up. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Trackpad Preferences in System Preferences. Under the *'More Gestures'* tab.